# Windows 8.1 PC settings disappeared, can't reset the OS

Tags: windows-8.1

My Dell PC with Windows 8.1 hardly functions anymore, and I got it just a year or so ago.

I tried all the well known "cleaning" programs [malware byte, tuneup utilities, advanced system care] to non avail.

I suppose i may have to reset the windows to the original factory state, which is far from ideal of course, aving to spend a lot of installation time again.

I saw how to do this on you tube but when i want to reach the setting to do this the computer refuses.

Clicking on ***change pc settings*** brings me back to the start up screen and even after many trials and after restarting the computer.

What should my next step be?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What is your actual question? "*Any suggestions*" is way to broad. Are you wanting to know how to clean your computer, save your data, reset it, what? Please **[edit]** your question to include more details

Comment: What is the issue? Do you mean it's slow? Cannot run applications? What antivirus are you using... could it be malware?

Comment: Are you having a hard time with reinstalling windows? Since it is a dell, I assume there is a recovery partition? You would have to press the key stroke required when booting, then follow the normal windows installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Please try booting with the {F8} key, to invoke Safe Mode. Once you boot into Windows, then select ***Change PC Settings***.

Should that fail, do {Win-R} and then paste this into the box to run the PC Settings change control:

```
Explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Windows.ImmersiveControlPanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain what running the Explorer command should do?

Comment: It will run the PC Settings Change Control.